# Drag and drop contents from one table to another using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

Maybe it is something simple but I cannot get this right.

I have a table with data, say, 4 columns and 4 rows. I want to enter the data items from this table into another table which has the same dimensions but each cell has an id which I use to save the data to a database. Currently I am entering the data from the table manually into the second table, which is time consuming because I have to do that often.

I believe that it can be possible by using drag and drop. I am using kendoui, which has drag and drop functionality but I simply cannot figure out how to do it with kendoui and whether that is possible.

Is this something that can be done relatively simple (with or without kendoui)? If so, can anyone give me some pointers on how to approach it?

Answer (score 0):

If you search this site probably you would get the solution. Anyways I found something following on this website but don't remember the link to actual post. Anyways :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$tabs = $(".tabbable");

$('.nav-tabs a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab('show');
})

$( "tbody.connectedSortable" )
    .sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        items: "> tr:not(:first)",
        appendTo: $tabs,
        helper:"clone",
        zIndex: 999990,
        start: function(){ $tabs.addClass("dragging") },
        stop: function(){ $tabs.removeClass("dragging") }
    })
    .disableSelection()
;

var $tab_items = $( ".nav-tabs > li", $tabs ).droppable({
  accept: ".connectedSortable tr",
  hoverClass: "ui-state-hover",
  over: function( event, ui ) {
    var $item = $( this );
    $item.find("a").tab("show");

  },
  drop: function( event, ui ) {
    return false;
  }
});
```

});

try this on jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Kzf62/18/