# How to move content from one row of the table to another table row using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

**I have two tables.Table 1 and table 2.I want to copy one row content to another when click on the that row instead of button ,using java-script.**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("t1").clone().appendTo("t2");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

 <table style="width:100%;border-style:dashed">
  <tr1>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr1>
  
</table> 
</br>
<table style="width:100%;border-style:dashed">
  <tr2>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr2>
  
</table>


<button>colne</button>

</body>
</html>
```

i will appreciate if codepen example be given.

Comment: Can you share the script which you have tried ?

Comment: i am new here .and i do not know how to share script.

Comment: i will appreciate if codepen example be given.....

Comment: Have you tried jQuery `clone()` Method. Please share your efforts so that we can help you better

Comment: i have image but and error is appearing you need 10 budges to upload images.

Answer (score 0):

You might trying to achieve this using

```
.droppable
```

[Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16422722/drag-and-drop-contents-from-one-table-to-another-using-jquery)

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/martyk/Kzf62/18/)

Comment: i only need "row content" move to another by clicking on that row.do not need to drop content by dragging it.

Comment: Why can't you use HTML5 drag and drop events [Check "The DataTransfer object"](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/)

Answer (score 0):

should be a simple matter of jquery dom manipulation, consider this:

```
<table id="first-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row-copier"><td>Content here</td><td>other content</td></tr>
    <tr class="row-copier"><td>more content</td><td>second column</td></tr>
    <tr class="row-copier"><td>...and something completely different</td><td><h1>YAY!</h1></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<table id="second-table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Result Table</td><td>where stuff will get copied</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.row-copier').click(function() {
    // select row-copier row, clone it, and append to second table body
    $(this).clone().appendTo('#second-table>tbody');
  });
});
</script>
```

the important bits are the `clone` operation to make a deep copy, and the `appendTo` to specify where the clone copy is being put.  I edited the answer to reflect your desire to copy the row clicking anywhere on the row itself, so no links are required, nor a `closest` to get the row.

good luck!

Comment: you can try copying the code to codepen yourself, just tested locally and it works fine -- if you understand the concept you should be able to implement it :)

Comment: jQuery(function($) { toekn arror on that line

Comment: did you include jquery?  since your question was tagged jquery i sort of assumed you knew to do that ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
                var items = [];

                $("#myTable tr").on("click", function() {
                    var newTr = $(this).closest("tr").clone();

                    var newButtonHTML = "<input type = 'button' value='Edit' onclick='Edit()' /><input type='button' value='Delete' onclick='deleteRow(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex)'/>";
                    $(newButtonHTML).children("button").click(function(e) {
                    });

                    $(newTr).children("td:last").html("").html(newButtonHTML);
                    items.push(newTr);
                    newTr.appendTo($("#stopsTable"));

                });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="height: 700px;width: 100%;overflow: auto; float: left;">
            <table id="myTable" border="1px" style="width: 24%; font-size: 10px; float :left;" >
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>S No</th>
                        <th>Stop Name</th>
                        <th>Longitude</th>
                        <th>Latitude</th>
                        <th>ETA</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                     
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr  >

                        <td >1</td>
                        <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
                        <td>28.56137</td>
                        <td>77.05249</td>
                        <td>06:06:12</td>
                        <td>Ignition_On</td>
            

                    </tr>


                    <tr  >

                        <td >2</td>
                        <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
                        <td>28.56136</td>
                        <td>77.05246</td>
                        <td>06:06:23</td>
                        <td>Ignition_On</td>
                   
                    </tr>


                    <tr  >

                        <td >3</td>
                        <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
                        <td>28.56135</td>
                        <td>77.05242</td>
                        <td>06:06:31</td>
                        <td>Start</td>
                 
                    </tr>


                    <tr  >

                        <td >4</td>
                        <td>The Indian Heights School</td>
                        <td>28.56139</td>
                        <td>77.05245</td>
                        <td>06:06:41</td>
                        <td>Ignition_On</td>
                       
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
    </table>
    
      <table id="stopsTable" border="1px" style="width: 24%; margin-left: 10px; font-size: 10px; float :left;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <th>S No</th>
                        <th>Stop Name</th>
                        <th>Longitude</th>
                        <th>Latitude</th>
                        <th>ETA</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                      
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                </tbody>
            </table>
```

Just see my code in this example .I think it will be help full for you and other friends.